Do i need to reauthenticate when using Odoo external API?
In the documentation part for logging in , it says that that u get a user identifier after calling authenticate. I am calling odoo api to update details after some event in my main app. Do i need to reauthenticate for each call? If not, how long can i save the value for future use. The value is just a uid, i'm wondering if i can keep this in memory and use it while my app is running.
